# Implementar la función eliminar en C (sin utilizar funciones predefinidas)

Tags: c, string

Este programa pretende implementar la función eliminar (sin utiliar funciones predefinidas), que consiste en quitar o borrar una subcadena de una cadena mayor

Sintaxis:
eliminar (Cadena, Índice, Cantidad)

El argumento cadena puede ser cualquier cadena. Índice especifica a partir de que posición se comenzará a eliminar la Cantidad de caracteres.

Ejemplo: La sentencia `printf("%s", strcpy(sstr,eliminar(str, pos, l)));` cuando pos = 13 y l = 3 y el arreglo cargado con la cadena str con la cadena Programación 1 debería imprimir la cadena "Programación" pero en cambio imprime " 1"

en definitiva, lo que hace es lo inverso de lo que quiero, elimina la cadena que debe mostrar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * eliminar(char str[], int pos, int l);

int main()
{
    char str[100], sstr[100];
    int pos, l;

    printf("Ingrese la cadena: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    printf("Introduzca la posicion para iniciar la extraccion: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    printf("Ingrese la longitud de la subcadena: ");
    scanf("%d", &l);

    strcpy(sstr,eliminar(str, pos, l));

    printf("%s", sstr);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

char * eliminar(char str[], int pos, int l)
{
    static char sstr[100];
    int c = 0;
    while (c < l)
    {
        sstr[c] = str[pos+c-1];
        c++;
    }
    sstr[c] = '\0';

    return sstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongamos un ejemplo. Tienes la cadena "ciento un perros" y quieres eliminar 5 caracteres desde la posición 4 te quedaría "cien perros".

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Original | c | i | e | n | t | o |  | u | n |  | p | e | r | r | o | s |
| Resultado | c | i | e | n |  | p | e | r | r | o | s |  |  |  |  |  |

Eliminar una parte de la cadena significa desplazar caracteres.

Puedes ver que el caracter de la posición 4 pasa a ser el de la posición 9, el de la 5 el 10 y así.

En código la instrucción equivalente sería

```
str[4] = str[9];
str[5] = str[10];
...
```

Nota que la diferencia entre ambas posiciones es 5. Entonces puedes ponerlo en un ciclo así:

```
// pos en este caso sería 4 y tam 15
for (int i = pos; i < tam - cant; i++){
    str[i] = str[i + cant];
}
```

`i` llega hasta `tam - cant` porque ahora la cadena es más pequeña.

Por último agregas un carácter nulo al final:

```
str[tam - cant + 1] = 0;
```

El cuidado que hay que tener es que la posición sea válida. Eso lo puedes hacer verificando que sea menor a tam y te queda un código así:

```
void eliminar(char str[], int tam, int pos, int cant)
{
    for (int i = pos; i < tam; i++){
        str[i] = (i + cant < tam) ? str[i + cant] : 0;
    }
    str[tam - cant] = 0;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##nVLNbhMxEL77KYagonWToK16IwUOXODMsYkq1@vdjrQZR7YXQVEehmfhwcKM7Wz5US/4NJ5vfr6Z@ex6sPZ0eolkx6lzcBNTh/71wzv1uysgDeJTXzx24EbcI5nQ2AcTgNHb3QqQEiSzL8bBx2JYQ0lvlJLISxhcinexpF1y3goiPrq7BKS/K@CHPTQveglrMkwcwXxI6wzLCy5NgaDlojmDm4yO4K3wILZqIjcVWMgJvIarHce0xVtrMLhRR6Wkxt4gNVoVGvNcV23Lo8WzuZlb5gFluErjwBtKfbP4RENw0cFoGO0cGXgDi8qlTj/P7Xvpof@pkILvpkdrpAj3QYue4GCC4c78YWoMuK8pGCvQU4PIhLjCBS5W8Ioz9fPkRk8DpqmDLn/jdF/oPlPsfMa6Unv41sQyRx5A3LMoZqAeQ6@etvU3oy1t6UNtfBG39BlJjEXOL4vXf5yszQf7LxXW2/Y@QCNOZD1wxIaNG8lhY7msOjxLB0U0CMtcoYTB@4JU544PXFV1nPdzK3HrimfVHU@nj15E4fceXEw/f0R1Dde/AA).

---

Ajustándose un poco más a como lo tienes en tu código:

```
char * remover(char str[], int pos, int l)
{
    int tam = strlen(str);
    static char sstr [100] = { 0 };

    // Copia el inicio de la cadena
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        sstr[i] = str[i];

    while (pos <= tam)
    {
        if (pos + l < tam)
            sstr[pos] = str[pos + l];
        pos++;
    }

    sstr[tam - l] = 0;

    return sstr;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##lVPNbtswDL77KTgPHew4WV30tqTboZftvOMSFJosOwQcKpAUbGjRh9mz7MEyUpLdBUMP88WUPvL7@Ce9GrQ@n98i6fHUGdj40KF9v/9Y/H3lkAa5K/ReOViAGfGApFwVz4x/2y0BKcDR@mSM9Tp5L2AwwT/45Lpg3yV4fDQPAah@KoA/7KF604tbFWFiD86C6jrC8jkTTo6gZdIYIQqG4E60ia0cyKICS0ICr@Bmxz5tus0cDK6L56IQjoNCquoipTHXctO2XI6fzPUsGavTikJO48h9CX1VfqHBGW9gVIx2hhR8gDLnkquf67a9aNT/MARnu9OjVkLCOqjREhyVU6zMB06NAfMzOKUFehHwnBAzXGG5hHccWb@e3GhpwHDqoItHf/qe0n2FTCqd2C4H31lu67wEsba5N5lpkt/Slu6zypXf0lckMUqZMYfNhPXFkNo4ov/YtjxDOQR1SIuR92JeChVQ5ylPs2XHsswlXl/DvT0id3lMPbe5T6lJ0ae3DioRwbhX/NtIFmw0zcu2RnrcpSzYyAI/9jgaqNgfNneSZop4uoxjWCKjWwMjC4gnfMqY3O14v/JSA8zRDDZNun1OgpFP2rFinmZ6DDlkeg7pPZzPn62Uag8WjA@/f/niFm7/AA).

---

En cuanto a tu otra duda, la primera vez que llamas a la función, el valor de sstr es desconocido:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | 98 | 99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sstr | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ... | ? | ? |

No quieres que la se elimine la subcadena de la cadena original, sino de una **copia**.

Si solo te limitas a hacer el "desplazamiento", `sstr` sigue teniendo valores indeterminados, bien podrían ser 0s (caracteres nulos) y por ese motivo no se imprime nada.

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sstr | ? | ? | ? | ? |  | p | e | r | r | o | s |

Antes de hacer el "desplazamiento", bien podrías copiar toda la cadena a `sstr` o solo la parte necesaria. Eso último es lo que hace el `for` justo entre `sstr` y el `while`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero me gustaría más aplicado a la pregunta

Comment: @AlejandroCaro ¿A qué te refieres con 'más aplicado a la pregunta'? ¿Quieres decir que se tome como base tu implementación original de la función `eliminar`?

Comment: Igual lo estoy modificando para quede lo más próximo al original pero manteniendo el resultado esperado

Comment: @Alejandro si el parámetro `tam` (porque es necesario saber el tamaño del arreglo) molesta, como alternativa puedes calcular la longitud de la cadena con `strlen`.

Comment: Si, hice eso y estoy tratando de que sea eliminar sea una función y no un procedimiento. Necesito que devuelva la cadena.

Comment: Lo pasé a función pero tengo problemas con el printf

Comment: @Alejandro elegí modificar la cadena que recibe la función por una razón: si tienes cadenas de más de 100 caracteres no funcionará. Bien podría usar memoria dinámica, pero prefiero dejar la tarea de reservar memoria a la función que llame `eliminar`.

Comment: No, con memoria estática está bien

Comment: Hago esto:     strcpy(sstr, eliminar(str, pos, l));

    printf("%s", sstr);
    pero no me muestra nada, no sé por qué

Comment: @Alejandro ahora sí. No muestra nada porque sstr está sin inicializar y la primera parte de la cadena no estaba siendo copiada en tu versión del código.

Comment: Si sstr es lo que devuelve la función ¿Hay que inicializar la variabe cadena de todos modos?

Comment: Intento pasarlo a pseudocódigo ¿Hay alguna forma de que funcione?

Comment: Hay un error en la función. Algunos ingresos dan mal. Por ejemplo Hola como estás indice 3 y longitud 3 debería dar holcomo estás cuando da hol (deja la cadena a medias)

Comment: @Alejandro da bien. Lo que tu dices debe dar **Holomo estás**. No sé que estarás haciendo diferente.

Comment: Entonces tengo un error en la devolución de la función que yo implementé. La tuya anda viene. Pero insisto, yo necesito que sea eliminar sea una función, no un procedimiento, es decir que devuelva la cadena.

Comment: Para que devuelva una cadena nueva e independiente de las demás, lo suyo sería usar memoria dinámica. Por eso propuse un enfoque bastante usado: que quien llame al función se encargue de pasar un puntero válido ya sea al stack o al heap.

Comment: Eso sería una forma de solucionarlo, pero ya que lo quiero portar a Pseudocódigo no quiero usar memoria dinámica. Igual ya o corregí cambiando la inicialización =""; por = {0}; Quedaría así: static char sstr [100] = { 0 };

Comment: @Alejandro Usar una cadena vacía es equivalente a una lista de 0s ( `{ 0 }` o si prefieres `{ }` ). Lo que si puede estar arreglando el problema es la otra modificación que hiciste. Si quieres seguir la conversación que sea en el [chat]. Ya es muy larga. Si tienes más problemas o preguntas,  [formula una nueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).