# como eliminar un numero determinado de caracteres en una posicion determinada

Tags: c, string, caracteres

el dia de hoy estoy haciendo este ejercicio que consiste en dada una cadena, eliminar n caracteres de una posición p, el caso es que no me sale el ejercicio ya que tampoco se como eliminar caracteres de una cadena en lenguaje c, adjunto codigo, agradezco mucho la ayuda, tengo un examen de c el viernes y me gustaria aprobarlo ya que me cuesta mucho aprender programación.

```
#include <string.h>

void eliminarcaracteres(char v[], int p, int n, char r[]);
int main() {
    int p,n;
   char cad[]={"fraseparaeliminarcaracteres"};
   char cad2[50];
    printf("introduce la posicion a eliminar caracteres");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    printf("Introduce el numero de caracteres a eliminar");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    eliminarcaracteres(cad,p,n,cad2);
    printf(" la palabra queda como %s",cad2);

}

void eliminarcaracteres(char v[], int p, int n,char r[]){
int l,i;
l= strlen(v);
int ini;
ini = p;
    for (i = ini ; (i  < n)  && (i < l) ; i++) {
        r[i]=v[i];

    }
if(n<l) r[n]= '\0';
else
    r[l]='\0';
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Implementar la función eliminar en C (sin utilizar funciones predefinidas)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577134/implementar-la-funci%c3%b3n-eliminar-en-c-sin-utilizar-funciones-predefinidas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código el resultado siempre será el final de una cadena con '\0'
y la función eliminarcaracteres que propones no cambia el valor de cad2[].
para ello necesitas pasar por referencia através de un puntero o que la función devuelva un valor para poder asignarlo a cad2[].

he cambiado de void a booleano por si se produce un fallo, ya que los valores introducidos pueden estar fuera de rango. si lo puedes quitar si quieres y dejarla en void pero no podrás controlar los valores introducidos en teclado.

```
bool eliminarcaracteres(char *cad, int pos, int cantidad);

int main() 
{
int p, n= 0;
char cad[] = "fraseparaeliminarcaracteres";

printf("introduce la posicion a eliminar caracteres");
scanf("%d", &p);
printf("Introduce el numero de caracteres a eliminar");
scanf("%d", &n);


bool resultado = eliminarcaracteres(cad, pos, cantidad);

if (resultado)
{
    printf("\nla palabra queda como %s", cad);
}
else 
{
    printf("\nHa ocurrido un fallo!");
}

return 0;
}




bool eliminarcaracteres(char *cad, int pos, int cantidad)
{
int longitud = strlen(cad);

if (pos >= longitud) // se comprueba si pos llega hasta '\0' o sobrepasa
{
    return false;

}

for (int x = pos; x < longitud; x++)
{
    cad[x] = cad[x + cantidad];
}
}
```